# Retrieving dynamically generated HTML using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screen-scraping, bookmarklet

I am making a bookmarklet which replaces the headings of news articles on [this](http://www.stuff.co.nz/) website with comments from within the article. I have written some code which finds all the links, accesses the article, and looks for the comments:

```
javascript:(function() { 
    $("h1,h2,h3,p").each(function() { //loops through all the h1, h2, and h3 elements
        var link = $(this).find('a');//creates a variable for the a element
            var url = $(this).find('a').attr("href");//creates a variable for the link attribute
            $.get(url, function(data) {//goes to each link
                var comments = $(data).find("#commentsDiv-comments");//finds the comments
                if ($(comments).length) {//if comments length exists, return comments
                    $(link).html(comments);                         
                } else {
                    $(link).html("No comments");//otherwise, return "no comment"
                }
            });
        });
    })();
```

The problem is, the comment html is generated by a script, and this script is not running before my bookmarklet accesses the article's html. Because of this, my bookmarklet cannot find any comments and it is returning "no comment" for every single article.

I have seen some answers on stackoverflow about this, but all of them seem to require other libraries etc and I'm not sure how to use these in a bookmarklet. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: could you trigger the script needed to load the comments before performing the scraping?

Comment: I looked into this but I'm not sure how to do it.